# How to use TFDJSONDataSets or similar in XE4?

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe4, datasnap, firedac

## Explanation

Today i have spotted the Delphi XE6 Sample called `FireDACJSONReflect` and i would to use the way it does the communication between the datasnap server and the client, i want to do it on **Mine application** using `TFDMemTable`and `TFDJSONDataSets`(not really needed, but if there is another way using another components i would like to see it).

### ** Mine application is a [delphi-xe4](/questions/tagged/delphi-xe4) server and a [delphi-xe6](/questions/tagged/delphi-xe6) client **

## Problem

By the way, my application does use Delphi XE4 instead of Delphi XE6 and want to know what to do to communicate between the datasnap server and the client the same way that `FireDACJSONReflect` does but i see that i cant have `TFDJSONDataSets` on my project uses list.

- Can i use `TFDJSONDataSets` on Delphi XE4?
- Can i use `TFDMemTable` without using `TFDJSONDataSets` to populate it with data?

## Some code

I have that lines of code running ok on delphi xe6 and i want to do the same in xe4:

```
function TDSSMetodoFinanceiro.getCotacaoLista : TFDJSONDataSets;
var 
  FDQCotacaoLista : TADQuery;
begin
  Result := TFDJSONDataSets.create;
  TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.listAdd(result, FDQCotacaoLista);
end;
```

**And the question**: Why i want to result a `TFDJSONDataSet`?

Its because i have a `TFDMemTable` on my delphi xe6 client application that i want to `.appendData` and it needs a `TFDJSONDataset` to do it(maybe another way to append data do it is useful).

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

TFDJSONDatasets is, I believe, introduced in XE6, so you cannot use this in earlier versions like XE4.  However, I think the job can be done with a FDMemtable instead.
Check out this [tutorial](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/sarinadupont/2013/12/23/using-fdmemtable-with-rest/), it was written for XE5 but I think this must work in XE4 too.
It starts of from some other [example](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/jtembarcadero/2013/12/19/no-time-endlesss-possibilities-with-rest-for-vcl-and-fm/) using a Clientdataset, but is then reworked to use a Firedac Memory table.
I should say, give it a try and see if it works out for you.